# How to insert many columns into such matrix in python

Tags: python, matlab

Suppose I have a matrix of dimension `4 x 4`, and I need to add the sum of columns 1 and 2 into the end of that matrix, and then 1 and 3, then the 1 and 4 and so on.

For example I have a random matrix `h` whose size is 4 x 4, then I need to insert a column into the end of it, then it will become of size 4 x 5.

In MATLAB, All simply,  I can do it as below :

```
clear all 
clc 

h = randn(4,4) + j*randn(4,4); 
h1 = h(:,1) + h(:,2);
h2 = h(:,1) + h(:,3);
h3 = h(:,1) + h(:,4);
h4 = h(:,2) + h(:,3);

h21 = [h h1 h2 h3 h4]
```

So `h21` is a matrix includes the original matrix `h` and the inserted columns into the end of it. That's ok.

Now, coming to pythong,  when using numpy.append , It says that append() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 5 were given, Even if I only took three inputs, that gives an error  ..  here is the code I tried :

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
h = np.random.randint(0, 10, (2, 4))

# array([[6, 3, 7, 4],
#        [6, 9, 2, 6]])

h2 = h[:, 0] + h[:, 1]     # array([ 9, 15])
h3 = h[:, 0] + h[:, 2]     # array([13,  8])

h21 = np.append(h, h2, h3)
print(h21)
```

Even if I used `concatenate` instead of `append`, gives a mistake that in `concatenate` dimensions of inputs should be equals. I also tried replacing  `append` by `extend`, and it gives mistake to.

expected result:

```
array([[ 6,  3,  7,  4,  9, 13],
       [ 6,  9,  2,  6, 15,  8]])
```

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can append only one element but it can be list with many columns

And you have to define `axis=0` to add rows or `axis=1` to add columns

```
h21 = np.append(h, [h2, h3, h4, h5], axis=1)

print(h21)
```

Without `axis` it create flattened list.

---

EDIT: numpy treads `h2` in `[h2, h3, h4, h5]` as row (as usually) so it needs to be transposed

```
hx = np.array([h2, h3, h4, h5]).T

h21 = np.append(h, hx, axis=1)
```

It is better visible when array has integer values

```
import numpy as np

h = np.array([
    [1,2,3,4],
    [1,2,3,4],
    [1,2,3,4],
    [1,2,3,4],
])

h2 = h[:,0] + h[:,1]
h3 = h[:,0] + h[:,2]
h4 = h[:,0] + h[:,3]
h5 = h[:,1] + h[:,2]
print(h2)

hx = np.array([h2, h3, h4, h5]).T
print(hx)

h21 = np.append(h, hx, axis=1)
print(h21)
```

With transposition

```
[[1 2 3 4 3 4 5 5]
 [1 2 3 4 3 4 5 5]
 [1 2 3 4 3 4 5 5]
 [1 2 3 4 3 4 5 5]]
```

Without transposition

```
[[1 2 3 4 3 3 3 3]
 [1 2 3 4 4 4 4 4]
 [1 2 3 4 5 5 5 5]
 [1 2 3 4 5 5 5 5]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, is there any other method where I can append many columns at  one time ?

Comment: see new text in answer

Comment: I added information about `axis=1` which can be important

Comment: sorry, but imho this answer was a qittle too quick. without axis kwarg, the matrices are flattened and you'll get a 1d array of all elements in one line. and to apply the axis kwarg, just a hint to it is not enough, because it will lead to an error if the arrays in `np.append()` do not have trhe same number of dimensions, which they don't have here.

Comment: @furas,  sorry, are you sure that dimension of h21 should be 4 x 8 ??  here with me I get it with dimension of 32 x 1 !

Comment: @SpghttCd  Yes, I exactly got that same thing.  so please how can I solve that !

Comment: Ok, now it seems to work. However - I think they need `axis=0`, what do you think...?

Comment: @SpghttCd in question I see `"insert columns"` and `axis=1` gives me shape `(4,8)` which means 4 rows, 8 columns - so it rather needs `axis=1`. OP also mentions `(4,8)` in some comment.

Comment: Correct, I didn't realize that obvious keyword :-)

Comment: Sorry again, I think this is still not what OP wants. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but IMO they want to have appended each of (h2, h3, h4, h5) as new columns in their matrix, right? But with your code, h2 is not the 5th column, but fills new 4 elements in the first row... I definitely thin we need an example here to trace what's going on.

Comment: @SpghttCd , I'm still new in Python, I'm not sure what you mean, could you please provide me an example ?

Comment: @SpghttCd you are right, with random values it is hard to see it. I made array with integers and now I see it uses h2 as row in `[h2,...]` so it would need to transpose before use. `hx = np.array([h2, h3, h4, h5]).T` and then `h21 = np.append(h, hx, axis=1)`

Comment: Of course, I'd like to add it into your question, so everybody can refer to it. My approach would be to use no complex, integer numbers and an unequal number of rows and columns to better distinguish them.

Comment: @furas could you please update it in the code you provided in that above answer ?

Comment: I adde example which show problem and how to use transposition to resolve it. @SpghttCd

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
h = np.random.randint(0, 10, (2, 4))
# array([[6, 3, 7, 4],
#        [6, 9, 2, 6]])


h2 = h[:, 0] + h[:, 1]     # array([ 9, 15])
h3 = h[:, 0] + h[:, 2]     # array([13,  8])


hh = np.vstack((h2, h3)).T
# array([[ 9, 13],
#        [15,  8]])

h21 = np.append(h, hh, 1)

# array([[ 6,  3,  7,  4,  9, 13],
#        [ 6,  9,  2,  6, 15,  8]])
```

Comment: np.vstack-------Stack arrays in sequence vertically (row wise).

Comment: describe in answer, not in comment